# Pentaho kettle engine is breaking the jboss7.1.3 logging

Tags: jboss7.x, java-ee-6

We're currently developing a project in javaee6 we migrated from seam2.3. And we have a dependency on kettle-engine.

What I found was kettle-engine is causing the jboss logging to break down, I mean it's not logging. I tried with a fresh project and just include this project in the dependency and the same problem occurs.

Any idea why? I'm using javaee6 maven archetype and here's the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
    <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0-GA</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what pentaho-kettle is, but try passing -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false as a start parameter to see if that does anything.

Comment: Thanks @james-r-perkins, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: This is just a guess, but it could be that pentaho kettle is removing log handlers as part of it's initialization. I've seen this before with other 3rd party libraries. Not a lot, but some.

Comment: Thanks James for the reply, we're dropping the pentaho kettle and move on with ejb timers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our findings end in the conclusion that the technologies we're using jboss7.1.3/javaee6/pentaho kettle-engine are not compatible together. Fortunately we already started the plan to drop kettle-engine in favor of EJB Timers.

So what worked for me is to removed all kettle* dependencies.